# Convert or encode id "1_0xr__abc@xyz.com__abc@uvw.com__054gg" into a number srtring

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anything which can convert or encode this 
`id ="1_0xr__abc@xyz.com__abc@uvw.com__054gg"` into specific number string

For Example Lets say `id="abcd@er.com"` to be converted into any number string `"1233452556"`

It that possible to do that in javascript?

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Actually this id is being used by which is writtten in jquery and jquery will not accept this id because of special charecters ,so I want to convert into number string so that I would be able to access it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

you can hashing the string

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
      var hash = 0, i, chr, len;
      if (this.length == 0) return hash;
      for (i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        chr   = this.charCodeAt(i);
        hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
        hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
      }
      return hash;
    };
```

Source: http://werxltd.com/wp/2010/05/13/javascript-implementation-of-javas-string-hashcode-method/

to use

```
id="abcd@er.com".hashCode();
```

Comment: Is there any limitations with it??

Comment: Thanks @fedri for your solution and I got one more solution please have a look on it tell me if it consists any problem